# The first gear gets stuck

Tags: transmission

It's an automatic car, Nissan primera 2003, with 2000 cc. 
The problem: I am not sure completely, but I guess is the first gear gets stuck.

When I step on the accelerator(almost at the end of it ), the speedometer goes 20-40km/h and the tachometer goes crazy high, like 5-6 thousands. The engine makes some noise,but not very noisy. The gear box doesn't clunk when I engage it.

All indicators are functional. No oil leak.

Is there anyone know what the problem is. A nonprofessional mechanic let me change a new gear box which will cost more than 2000 New Zealand dollars. It's almost a half of the value of the car. One of my friend tested the car and found that the problem is that the first gear gets stuck.

I need your help. What should I do now? SOS

Comment: Welcome to the site. Has anyone checked the transmission fluid level?

Comment: yes. THe transmission fluid is good.

Comment: Does it behave the same if in a similar situation you accelerate slowly, without flooring the accelerator? By your flooring the pedal, the car's computer may simply be registering your action as "give me everything you've got!", and does just that by maintaining a low gear for as long as it is safe. If this hypothesis is correct, if you go easy on the pedal, it should shift up normally.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this on 2002 Primera.  The car is in safe mode so will not go faster than you said.  Common repairs are speed sensor or stepper motor related but the first thing to do is get a scanning tool to plug into your ecu. You can put the cvt transmission into diagnostic mode without tools and count the
"Sport Mode" light flashes for cvt errors.  Have you solved this problem yet?